# Cant initiate refresh action from a callback RefreshControl

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using a RefreshControl to initiate refreshing the screen after a button press, code below. However the refreshing doesn't start even after setting the state of the refresh variable.

```js
const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);
    ....

<ScrollView 
  style={styles.container} 
  refreshControl={
    <RefreshControl refreshing={refresh} />
  }
>
  ....
  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => {
      setRefresh(true);
      if (modal) {
        modal.close();
      }
    }}
  >
    ...
  </TouchableOpacity>
</ScrollView>
```

I am able to initiate refresh action from API callback but same doesn't work from button callback. Not sure what's needed here.

Answer (score 0):

As a documentation :

> Note: refreshing is a controlled prop, this is why it needs to be set to true in the onRefresh function otherwise the refresh indicator will stop immediately.

So, you have to set `refresh` to true in `onRefresh()` method.

```js
const onRefresh = React.useCallback(() => {
    setRefresh(true);

    // your api call
    setRefresh(false);
}, [refreshing]);
```